# How to sync push notification between devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, notifications, synchronization

I have a small question about push notification sync between devices.

For instance, I'm building an iOS and an OSX app.
Both of them support push notifications and I send notifications to both devices at the same time.

Is it possible to "hide/dismiss" the push notification (or change badge) on an OSX device if I opened a push notification on my iOS device?
Like iMessages does.

I can't find any Apple API or third party service that does somthing like that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Improved some grammar and some formatting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Does your app communicating with any server? If yes you can send information like "user-saw-content" to the server then send another push notification to cancel others notifcations if necessary.

Comment: Yes, my app communicates with my server. So, writing my own sync system is the only way?